# Cell size of rotated overlapped honeycomb lattices (moire pattern)

Tags: geometry

Assuming there are two infinity large honeycomb lattices, whose side lengths of their smallest hexagons are *a* and *b*, respectively. When one lattice rotates *θ* relatively to another lattice, a Moire pattern appears which has different repeating unit cells with side length *m*. What is relation between *m*, *a*, *b* and *θ*? In wiki([Moire pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)), a solution is given when *a*=*b*.

Comment: I strongly advise to delve into the very good 2 books on "Moiré patterns" By [Isaac Amidror] (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84882-181-1)

Comment: What have you observed ? Have you attempted Fourier Transform ?

Comment: I tried computer programming with Fourier Transform, but can only get some numerical results. Previously I read the chapter 2 of this book, formula like (2.9) only works when T1~T2. When I simulated two lattices with very different sizes, the error can be up to around 10%